# Replace value in query string with new value PHP

Tags: php, function

I've got a URL that I'm wanting to replace values if they're there, but add if they're not.

My URL would be for example: `http://www.example.com/online/admin/users?p=Name&sort=user&dir=desc` and I want to write a script that will write out the queries in the URL again if it exists already or add it if it doesn't. I want to the write it to an "a" tag but with the different value I select for sort and dir

I found some code at a website called [Add Querystring Variable](http://www.addedbytes.com/code/php-querystring-functions/)

```
function add_querystring_var($url, $key, $value) {
    $url = preg_replace('/(.*)(?|&)' . $key . '=[^&]+?(&)(.*)/i', '$1$2$4', $url . '&');
    $url = substr($url, 0, -1);
    if (strpos($url, '?') === false) {
        return ($url . '?' . $key . '=' . $value);
    } else {
        return ($url . '&' . $key . '=' . $value);
    }
}
```

My only problem is I'm not sure how to use it to do what I want.

This is the code I've got so far to go with it

```
add_querystring_var("http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],"sort","lvl");
add_querystring_var("http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],"dir","asc");
```

But I don't know what to do from here as that isn't writing anything out for me.

I know it will be simple but I'm new to this area of PHP. :D

**EDIT**

Code so far

```
$url='http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
function add_querystring_var($url, $key, $value) {
    $urlarray = parse_url($url);
    parse_str($urlarray['query'],$queryarray);
    $queryarray[$key]=$value;
    $queryarray = http_build_query($queryarray);
    return http_build_url($url,array('query'=>$queryarray),HTTP_URL_JOIN_QUERY);
}
$url_id=add_querystring_var($url,"sort","lvl");
$url_id=add_querystring_var($url,"dir",$dir);

<?php echo '<a href="'.$url.'">New Anchor</a>'; ?>
```

But this returned blank. Any more ideas at all? Thanks for all the input so far guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend to use [parse_url](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) and [parse_str](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php)

```
function add_querystring_var($url, $key, $value) {
    $urlarray = explode('?',$url);
    $query = '';
    if(isset($urlarray[1]))
        $query = $urlarray[1];
    parse_str($query,$queryarray);
    $queryarray[$key]=$value;
    $queryarray = http_build_query($queryarray);

    return $urlarray[0].'?'.$queryarray;
}
```

call like this

```
add_querystring_var("http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],'sort','id');
```

or for your specific case

```
<?php 
$url='http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$url=add_querystring_var($url,"sort","lvl");
$url=add_querystring_var($url,"dir", $dir);
echo '<a href="'.$url.'">New Anchor</a>'; 
?>
```

Tested

Comment: That needs to be `parse_str($urlarray['query'], $queryarray)`.

Comment: It should be pointed out that `http_build_url` is a PECL extension.

Comment: Thanks but that seemed to break something. This is what is in my a tag: `<a href="<?php add_querystring_var("http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],"sort","id"); ?>">`. Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: see the solution above now. I updated it. its working for me.

Answer (score 0):

Using what you've got so far, you may want to modify it a little like so:

```
$url='http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
//your add_querystring_var() returns the new url, it doesn't echo it to the screen
$url=add_querystring_var($url,"sort","lvl");
$url=add_querystring_var($url,"dir","asc");

echo '<a href="'.$url.'">New Anchor</a>';
```